# Npm publish gives invalid directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am currently working on a CLI to bootstrap react apps but I've run into a problem! I previously had made it in typescript and then I moved it over to javascript, like fully deleting everything and then making a fresh javascript project in that same directory and when I run any npm or yarn commands like `npm start` or any script that has to start a file is giving this output:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTDIR
npm ERR! path D:\Projects\npm-packages\reactize\index.js
npm ERR! ENOTDIR invalid cwd D:\Projects\Github projects\reactize\index.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sinha\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-07-01T04_30_47_911Z-debug.log
```

After This, I moved it over to a different directory thinking it will solve the problem but it didn't! exact same output with just the path difference now pointing to the folder I moved the project over to! Even `npm publish` is failing with the same error. Here is the full log:

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'publish'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@7.6.0
2 info using node@v15.11.0
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 3ms
4 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 7ms
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 8ms
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 3ms
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:file:D:\Projects\Github projects\reactize\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\sinha\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 2ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\sinha\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 2ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 22ms
19 verbose npm-session 861e538ded110b88
20 timing npm:load Completed in 44ms
21 verbose publish [ '.' ]
22 timing command:publish Completed in 14ms
23 verbose stack Error: ENOTDIR invalid cwd D:\Projects\Github projects\reactize\index.js
23 verbose stack     at Glob._readdirError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\glob\glob.js:592:21)
23 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\glob\glob.js:553:12
23 verbose stack     at go$readdir$cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:214:14)
23 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:190:23)
24 verbose cwd D:\Projects\Github projects\reactize
25 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
26 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "publish"
27 verbose node v15.11.0
28 verbose npm  v7.6.0
29 error code ENOTDIR
30 error path D:\Projects\Github projects\reactize\index.js
31 error ENOTDIR invalid cwd D:\Projects\Github projects\reactize\index.js
32 verbose exit 1
```

and here is the package.json:

```json
{
    "name": "reactize",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "description": "A simple way to bootstrap your react apps!",
    "main": "index.js",
    "directories": {
        "lib": "lib",
        "bin": "index.js"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node .",
        "test": "jest",
        "path": "yarn version --patch",
        "minor": "yarn version --minor",
        "major": "yarn version --major",
        "prepublishOnly": "node scripts/genTemplateFiles.js"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/YT-GameWorks/reactize.git"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "cli",
        "boilerplate",
        "electron",
        "react",
        "typescript"
    ],
    "author": "Game Glide <sinha.soham@outlook.com>",
    "license": "MIT",
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/YT-GameWorks/reactize/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/YT-GameWorks/reactize#readme",
    "dependencies": {
        "chalk": "^4.1.1",
        "consola": "^2.15.3",
        "enquirer": "^2.3.6",
        "execa": "^5.1.1",
        "fs-extra": "^10.0.0",
        "jest": "^27.0.6",
        "listr": "^0.14.3"
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that scripts like `yarn major` etc.. which have nothing to do with the project work properly.